# Reading XML file using DXL(DOORS Scripting) and exporting to EXCEL dynamically

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to read an XML file using DXL scripting and Exporting to EXCEl.

Is there any script in DXL already available?
Please help me out.
Thanks,
Sri

Comment: It can be done but there is no quick function built in to DXL to read XML, you have to build your own. Exporting to Excel is also possible by either going to Comma Separated Values or by using the OLE methods.

Comment: @SteveValliere why not using your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but there is no quick function built in to DXL to read XML, you have to build your own. Exporting to Excel is also possible by either going to Comma Separated Values or by using the OLE methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is one library created by **Mathias Mamtsch**, using it you can create DOM from input string xml, then read,write attributes, values, iterate over attributes ,tags and so on.

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxlstandardlib
```

In **DXL** world you have to write everything on you own.

It uses some helpers dxl files so to use it you have to use more than one additional dxl files.

For example one of the function there:

```
/*! \memberof XMLDocument 
    \return true - if the XML document could be loaded and parsed correctly. 'false' if there was an error loading the document.
    \param xd The XMLDocument into which the contents shall be loaded. 
    \param s the contents of the XML document to load
    \brief This function loads the XML content of a string into an XMLDocument object.     
*/  
bool loadXML (XMLDocument xd, string s) {
    bool result = false
    checkOLE (  oleMethod (getOleHandle_ xd, "LoadXML", oleArgs <- s, result)  )
    return result
}
```

These functions use OLE objects so I think they are Windows specific and under Linux the code will not work. But not sure.